# Help adjusting padding in complex longtable

Tags: longtable, tabularx, warnings, white-space

I'm working on a CV and decided to use a `longtable` to set everything so it can span multiple pages easily. Overall, I like the look of what I've arrived at, but there are a couple issues with padding that I'd like to fix:

- My pseudo-subheading lines (made using a nested `tabular*`) do not quite extend to the far right of the `longtable` column, though they do appear to start at the correct position on the left. I believe this corresponds to the first of two warnings I get about an underfull `\hbox`. (You can see the text doesn't go quite as far right as the text on the following line does.)
- There is leading and trailing vertical whitespace around the nested `itemize`, even though I am using the `nosep` option from `enumitem`.
- There is a little extra vertical space after the `longtable` environment ends.
- There is a warning issued about an underfull `\hbox` in alignment for the whole `longtable`. I don't think I've seen this issue with alignment before, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this or even identifying what specifically is causing it.

Here's the output of my MWE (red are annotations added by me, not part of output):

[image: Annotated image of minimum working example.]

And my MWE is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% No indentation.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

% Adjust longtable padding.
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\setlength\LTpre{2pt}  % A little pre-padding to look like a regular line.
\setlength\LTpost{0pt}

% Adjust itemize environments.
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,left=0pt,label=\raisebox{0.5ex}{\tiny$\bullet$}}

\begin{document}

Some text before the table.

% Without the minipage, there's extra space at the bottom of the table.
\begin{longtable}
  { @{} >{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}p{1in} @{\extracolsep{0.25in}} p{6.25in} @{} }% LINE 29
  & \begin{tabular*}{\hsize}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r @{}}% LINE 30
      Pseudo-Subheading & Other content
    \end{tabular*} \\
  Left text 1 & Very lengthy text content goes here, which (with enough words
                written) ought to span past the end of the line sufficiently to
                do some things. \\
  Left text 2 & %
                \begin{itemize}[after=\strut]
                \item Bullet point 1.
                \item Bullet point 2.
                \end{itemize} \\
  Left text 3 & Some regular text, just for effect.
\end{longtable} % LINE 42

Some text after the table.

\end{document}
```

There are two warnings given:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 4713) in paragraph at lines 30--30
 []||

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in alignment at lines 29--42
[] []
```

Maybe there's also a way to simplify my code, but I am not a LaTeX expert by any means. I've arrived at this solution after solving various problems along the way. The goal is to have two fixed columns of specified widths with a quarter-inch gap between them, where the left column is right-aligned and the right column is left-aligned, and to be able to sometimes have that right-hand column split into sub-columns for sub-headings, and also to be able to embed `itemize` environments without leading or trailing whitespace and no indentation.

Comment: you have the table inside a vbox inside a minipage both will prevent any page breaking so there is no point in using longtable here just use a tabular, (I don't think the setbox/usebox is doing anthing either.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your point — I didn't realize they would have that effect. I've removed the minipages and vbox. (I believe they were originally added because I wanted to wrap some frames around some boxes to see how far the alignment was off.) Removing these has further impacted other elements of the vertical whitespace, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some simplifications of your code, shown with (a) `longtable`, (b) using `tabular` and with (c) `tabularx` the extra spaces and misalignment (and bad boxes) are gone.

With `tabularx` the width of the second column is calculated automatically.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}% Not used here
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}   % Not used here

\usepackage{tabularx}% added <<<<<<<

\usepackage{showframe} % show the margins <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}

% No indentation.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
\newcommand{\markitem}{\raisebox{0.4ex}{\footnotesize\textbullet}~} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

% Adjust longtable padding.
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
%\setlength\LTright{0pt} % <<<<<<<<<
\setlength\LTpre{2pt}  % A little pre-padding to look like a regular line.
\setlength\LTpost{-2pt} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} % added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
Some text before the \textbf{longtable.}

\begin{longtable}{p{1in} @{\extracolsep{0.25in}} p{6.25in}}% LINE 29
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pseudo-Subheading \hfill Other content} \\
    Left text 1         & Very lengthy text content goes here, which (with enough words
    written) ought to span past the end of the line sufficiently to
    do some things. \\
    Left text 2         & \markitem Bullet point 1. \\
                        & \markitem Bullet point 2. \\
    Left text 3         & Some regular text, just for effect.
\end{longtable} % LINE 42

Some text after the longtable.

\bigskip

Some text before the \textbf{tabular.}  

    \begin{tabular}{p{1in} @{\extracolsep{0.25in}}   p{6.25in}}% LINE 29        
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pseudo-Subheading \hfill Other content} \\
    Left text 1         & Very lengthy text content goes here, which (with enough words written) ought to span past the end of the line sufficiently to do some things. \\
    Left text 2         & \markitem Bullet point 1. \\
                        & \markitem Bullet point 2. \\
    Left text 3         & Some regular text, just for effect.
\end{tabular} % LINE 42

Some text after the tabular.    

\bigskip

Some text before the \textbf{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1in} @{\extracolsep{0.25in}} X}% LINE 29
                        & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Pseudo-Subheading \hfill Other content} \\
    Left text 1         & Very lengthy text content goes here, which (with enough words
    written) ought to span past the end of the line sufficiently to
    do some things. \\
    Left text 2         & \markitem Bullet point 1. \\
                        & \markitem Bullet point 2. \\
    Left text 3         & Some regular text, just for effect.
\end{tabularx} % LINE 42

Some text after the tabularx.   
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much for such a thorough solution with all three methods! Am I right in thinking that if I want the table to easily span multiple pages, I should just stick with the `longtable`? Also, did you disable `\LTright` because it's automatically handled by specifying the width of the columns?

Comment: @Pierce Darragh To the first, yes. `\LTright` is irrelevant because you are using exactly the full width of the `textarea` = 7.5 in = 1 + 0.25 + 6.25 in but it gives an underfull warning, perhaps due to ?. The warning disappears with `\setlength\LTright{0.01pt}` !!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**
By use of `enumitem`, `etoolbox` and `tabularray` packages. With `enumitem` and `etoolbox` are defined stile of list `itemize` inside of `tblr` table, so you table body code you can still use of `itemize` list.

In the case that your table can be fit in one page, than you can replace all `longtblr` in MWE with `talltblr` and table insert in `table` float. .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tabularray}     % version 2021P
\UseTblrLibrary{varwidth}   % <===
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
\SetTblrStyle{head}{font=\small}
\SetTblrStyle{foot}{\small\itshape}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries}
                    }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{longtblr}{%
\setlist[itemize]{nosep,
                  itemsep=0.5ex,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\end{minipage},                  % <---
                  before=\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth} % <---
                  }
                        }
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begingroup
\begin{longtblr}[
    theme = fancy,
  caption = {The Long Table Caption},
    label = {tab:longtblr},
                ]{colspec={@{} l X[j] @{}},
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  rowhead=1,
                  measure = vbox,            % <===
                  }
            &   Pseudo-Subheading\hfill  Other content  \\
Left text 1 &   Very lengthy text content goes here, which (with enough words
                written) ought to span past the end of the line sufficiently to
                do some things. \\
Left text 2 &   \begin{itemize}
            \item Bullet point 1.
            \item Bullet point 2.
                \end{itemize}   \\
Left text 3 &   Some regular text, just for effect.
    \end{longtblr}\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\endgroup
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]